# dynamicreports mdx sample?

Tags: mdx, mondrian, dynamic-reports, olap4j

Does any one has a tutorial or a sample with dynamicReports using MDX query ?
I'm trying to create dynamic reports from the result of an MDX query using Mondrian as a ROLAP engine and olap4j as a driver.